# tmux configuration multiple variables

Tags: tmux

Getting errors for the last line. If for status right I only show either spotify or date it works. I cannot get it to show both. What am I missing?

```
tm_date="#[fg=$tm_color_inactive] %b %d - %I:%M"
tm_session_name="#[fg=$tm_color_feature,bold]$tm_icon #S"

set -g status-left $tm_session_name' '
set -g status-right '#(tmux-spotify-info)' '$tm_date
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is `tmux-spotify-info`? Is it similar to [tm_spotify](https://github.com/nicknisi/dotfiles/blob/master/tmux/theme.sh#L52)? If so, changing the line to this seems to fix it.

```
set -g status-right $tmux-spotify-info' '$tm_date
```

Comment: Yeah that was close. I ended up putting my sh name in a variable then doing

    tm_spotify="#(tmux-spotify-info)"
    set -g status-right $tm_spotify' '$tm_date